# How to build a 27 degree Celsius heat generator / heater

Tags: heat

How to build a 27°C heat generator / heater?

### Requirements

It must be able to generate heat such that the temperature at a radius of 2m from the generator will be at 27°C ± 1°C (26°C to 28°C)

There is no requirement on the power supply. I can use a battery, AC supply, or DC supply but please be energy efficient.

The physical environment is a office/room about 10m x 12m.

The complexity of this device should of course be as simple as possible. (who wants to work with too much complexity, right?)

I really cannot tell you the purpose but it is a experiment that needs to be carried out.

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: Please find my new edit.

Comment: Larry, if you accept Steven's answer, why not upvote it? (Upvoting is saying you find the answer useful, as the hint says when you hover over the up arrow.)

Comment: @FedericoRusso, I will upvote Steven answer if there is a better answer than Steven. From what I know, marking a solution as answer is 15 points but upvote it only give 10 points - am I right?

Comment: That's  right, 10 points for upvote, 15 for accepted answer. But they're independent, you can upvote AND accept, resulting in +25 rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a closed volume to get that precise temperatures, with well isolated walls. If it's open you'll have hot spots at the place of your heater(s), and a **temperature gradient** towards the edges of the volume you want to heat. You'll also need **forced convection**; natural convection won't suffice to get a good heat distribution. In a sauna the top benches are always several degrees hotter than the lower ones, for instance. A disadvantage of (forced) convection is that it increases the heat exchanged to the environment, read: **heat losses**, so that you'll need a more powerful heater.
As a heater you could use the heater from a water kettle, and control it with a thermostat. For the forced convection use one or more fans. This may not be enough to meet your \$\pm\$1°C precision, but it may be hard to get there anyway; 1°C is very tight.

**edit**
The kettle's heater would normally give its heat to the water in the kettle, which you don't have here. You'll need a fan to remove the heat from the heater, or it will burn quickly.

**edit 2** (re: comments)
You may wonder why no use an oil filled radiator? They're *made* to heat rooms. Oil filled radiators usually have more power than the kettle (mine is 2500W), but they react much slower too. You would need a **PID controller** to control the temperature, where with faster-reacting heaters like the kettle's an on/off control like a thermostat may be sufficient.

Comment: Would a red-colored light-blub perform the task of the heater from a water kettle?

Comment: @Larry - No. The red color doesn't increase the amount of radiated heat. Forget the filter; a bulb already emits around 95% heat. The thing is that a bulb doesn't give enough heat. Think about it: does your room heat up by 5°C when you have the lights on?

Comment: Nope, the room definitely will not be heat by by 5°C when it is turn on but I certainly need something that can make the temperature 27°C

Comment: @Larry - The bulb will be 60W, a water kettle easily 1000W-1500W, so that's 16 to 25 times more

Comment: got your point. but the problem is that I will need 3 equipments - kettle, fan, thermostat. I was wondering if I can use a simple equipments - maybe a 1000 W incandescent light-blub or something similar.

Comment: Thus, the problem will be how much watt can give a constant 27°C and given that the ±1°C precision & the distance can be compromise.

Comment: @Larry Morries - A fatally major problem here is that you have not told people enough about what you are trying to do. **AT** 2 meters may mean JUST at - before and after you don't care. Or you may mean the whole space out to 2 metres. And it may be enclosed or open, and it may be outside in winter in NYC, or indoors in summer in Florida. etc. If you want genuine answers you MUST ask genuine questions. Otherwise you just waste people's time with rubbish. Please give us a good description of your real problem - and we will give you superb answers :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, My original questions was indeed genuine but the problem is that currently no one was able to cater and answer the question perfectly. What should I do? It is either I wait for that perfect answer or I have to make some compromise to my question in order to award stevenvh the points right? If you were in my shoe, what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Larry - There are other solutions. I've got an oil-filled radiator, 2.5kW, but this reacts much too slow, so you would have to build a PID controller for it, which is more complicated than a simple thermostat. A 1000W light bulb will do as well as the kettle if you can stand the light. :-)

Comment: @stevenvh I appreciate your efforts in trying to get as close to the perfect answer. I will take your answer as my final answer.

Comment: @Larry Morries - The question may be ***GENUINE*** but the question is not **GOOD**. Now you have accepted a final answer where the person answering has no real idea of what you want, you have not told us what you want and we have absolutely no way of knowing if you really have an answer that suits you. A domestic fan heater with a decent thermostat MAY suit your need - and may not. Or a hair dryer. Or a vacuum cleaner. Or a 737-400 (thermostatic control may be difficult).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I like your sentence 'The question may be GENUINE but the question is not GOOD'. If my question is not Good, you can also feel free to leave your comments so that I can edit my question to fit it well. Of course, if your answer if to have a 737-400 as the "fan heater", it would be quite unreasonable - the 737-400 is very expensive right? The answer given by stevenh is consider quite well-done even though I know it is very hard to fulfill the 1°C precision.

Comment: @Larry You really need to provide more detail with your question.  Please edit your question and tell us a) The power supply requirements; b) the physical environment details; c) the complexity you are willing to work with; d) the purpose of the heating.

Comment: @Majenko, for your question, my answer as follows [a] no requirement on power supply. can use battery or AC supply or DC supply but please be energy efficient. [b] the physical environment is a office/room about 10m x 12m [c] the complexity would of course be as simple as possible. (who want to work with too much complexity, right?) [d] the purpose of heating - I really cannot tell you but it is a experiment that need to be carry out. Hope it help.

Comment: @Larry please edit your question and add the information so others can find it easily and write a good answer for you.

Comment: Oh, and is it a question of getting 27 degrees at a spot 2m away from the heater, or at a radius of 2m from the heater?

Comment: @Majenko, I have edit my question. as for the 27 degrees, it is a a radius of 2m from the heater (as written earlier)